# How to parse datetime returns from ToString

Tags: c#

When I use the following datetime format in the Windows calendar settings.

```
Short date: M/d
Long time: H:mm:ss
```

The following code can't work.

```
var s = DateTime.Now.ToString(); // 4/28 8:00:00
var b = DateTime.TryParse(s, out dt); // false
```

The string is returned from a library, so I cannot change it, <s>is it possible to write a parsing method that works for any kind of datetime format in the Windows calendar settings?</s>

---

Update, from @MathiasR.Jessen's suggestion, I have found a solution, but it is not elegant because I have to concatenate the format string manually.

```
var dtf = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
var fmt = dtf.ShortDatePattern + " " + dtf.LongTimePattern;
var b = DateTime.TryParseExact(s, fmt, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

Now the question changes to is there a better way?

Comment: Use `TryParseExact()` instead

Comment: How would you parse "5/4/2008" - is that April 5th or May 4th?

Comment: "any" datetime format as in: one method that is able to handle any and all formats? no, that's logically impossible. "any" format as in: any format you _specify_? [Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I mean the format in calendar settings.

Comment: @JonSkeet I mean the format in calendar settings.

Comment: How could you parse a date from that without a year? Is it this year, next year, last year or 100 years ago?

Comment: @Ergis I want to parse a string that is returned from `DateTime.ToString()`, since the format is configured in the Windows calendar settings which means the format is unsure, and for some kind of format `TryParse` will return false.

Comment: You can see from the source of `DateTime.ToString()` that it uses an internal property `GeneralLongTimePattern` which is initialized to `ShortDatePattern+" "+LongTImePattern` by default. Since you can't (easily) access the internal property, this is the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `DateTime.TryParse()` or `DateTime.Parse()` will not understand just any custom format. For custom datetime formats you need to use [DateTime.TryParseExact()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-6.0) and [DateTime.ParseExact()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0):

Here is a demo [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V3oOzR) with that would be able to parse your input string.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to parse any custom format, both remarks of `TryParse` and `ToString` say they use current culture, I feel suprise it cannot convert the string back.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use "DatetTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" it returns the value in year-shortMonth-date.
You can change the format according to your code.

Comment: Thanks, but the string is returned from a library, I can't change it.

Comment: I think In order to change the datetime format in C# we must parse it as a string .